# Is it possible to change the alignment of only 1 facet title

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggtext

Say I have a facetted ggplot like this:

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Species) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**Question:**

Is it possible to align only the 1st facet label ("setosa") to the left, but keep the others central?

I have not had any luck with straight `ggplot`, so I tried converting to a gtable (code below), and I can see that the element I probably need to modify is tableGrb #13 - strip-t-1, but I'm not sure how to do so. I tried changing the `gt$layout$l` and `gt$layout$r` values to 4 (was 5) but that moves the heading off the facet entirely.

```
pl <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Species) +
  geom_point()
gt <- ggplotGrob(pl)

gt$layout[gt$layout$name == 'strip-t-1', c('l', 'r')] <- c(4, 4) # my attempt
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Relevant issue on the ggplot2 github: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4201. Particularly, see Claus Wilke's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea but not the right spot. Basically you need to do something like this:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('grid')

data(iris)
pl <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Species) +
  geom_point()
gt <- ggplotGrob(pl)

gt$grobs[[13]]$grobs[[1]]$children$strip.text.x.top..titleGrob.186$children$GRID.text.184$x <- unit(0.1, 'npc')
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

But this won't work for you... it won't even work for me a second time since the `titleGrob.xxx` and `GRID.text.xxx` change each time you use `gt <- ggplotGrob(pl)`

So try a different method and knowing the location you need to edit as you have pointed out (it's in the first `strip`):

```
gp <- ggplotGrob(pl)
grid.ls(grid.force(gp))

# layout
#   background.1-13-13-1
#   panel-1-1.8-5-8-5
# ...
#   strip-t-1.7-5-7-5                        <- here
#     strip.1-1-1-1
#       strip.background.x..rect.533
#       strip.text.x.top..titleGrob.525
#         GRID.text.523
#   strip-t-2.7-7-7-7
#     strip.1-1-1-1
#       strip.background.x..rect.533
#       strip.text.x.top..titleGrob.528
#         GRID.text.526
#   strip-t-3.7-9-7-9
#     strip.1-1-1-1
#       strip.background.x..rect.533
#       strip.text.x.top..titleGrob.531
#         GRID.text.529
#   axis-t-1.6-5-6-5
# ...
#   title.3-9-3-5
#   caption.11-9-11-5
#   tag.2-2-2-2
```

You can use `gPath` to get the path without knowing the `GRID.text.xxx` in advance. Note that in your example, we can just edit the first `GRID.text` and it will work if `global = FALSE`, ie, if `global = TRUE`, all of them would change.

```
g1 <- editGrob(
  grid.force(gp),
  gPath('GRID.text'), grep = TRUE, global = FALSE,
  x = unit(0.25, 'npc')
)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]

However, you might need a very specific path, so follow the `strip-t-1` down to your `GRID.text` (note that `global = TRUE`, and it only affects one strip)

```
g2 <- editGrob(
  grid.force(gp),
  gPath('strip-t-1', 'strip', 'strip', 'GRID.text'), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
  x = unit(0.75, 'npc')
)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g2)
```

[image]

Comment: One small suggestion: `x = unit(0, 'npc'), hjust = 0` might be safer than `x = unit(0.25, 'npc')` on its own for left alignment, as the size of the plot / length of the facet title may vary in other use cases.

Comment: @Z.Lin would `just = 'left'` or `just = 'right'` work as well? I always have to try both `adj = 0` and `adj = 1` in base plots to remember which is left and right. this question reminded me why i avoid ggplot like the plague

Comment: `just = 'left'` (or right) should work if you also throw in `hjust = NULL`, since the latter overrides the former if specified. That's my understanding from `?grid::grid.text`.

Answer (score 7):

This is something that eventually the ggtext package should be able to do in a general way, but as of now its HTML rendering code is too limited. A new rendering engine is in the works that supports much more CSS, including CSS selectors, which makes it possible to target formatting to specific data values in a generic way. It also supports the `text-align` property you need to left-align text.

Below are two examples of how this can work. Once the new rendering engine is integrated into ggtext you won't need the helper code anymore.

```r
# packages needed
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(rlang)
library(sinab)  # remotes::install_github("clauswilke/sinab")

# helper code that will eventually live in the ggtext package
element_html <- function(css = NULL, family = NULL, face = NULL, size = NULL, colour = NULL, fill = NULL,
                         linetype = NULL, linewidth = NULL, hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, lineheight = NULL,
                         margin = NULL, width = NULL, height = NULL, color = NULL, 
                         debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE) {
  if (!is.null(color))
    colour <- color
  
  # doesn't work with other values at this time
  hjust <- 0
  vjust <- 1
  
  structure(
    list(
      css = css,
      family = family, face = face, size = size, colour = colour, fill = fill,
      linetype = linetype, linewidth = linewidth, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust,
      lineheight = lineheight, margin = margin, width = width, height = height,
      debug = debug, inherit.blank = inherit.blank),
    class = c("element_html", "element_text", "element")
  )
}

element_grob.element_html <- function(element, label = "", x = NULL, y = NULL,
                                      family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL,
                                      hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, lineheight = NULL,
                                      margin = NULL, ...) {
  if (is.null(label))
    return(ggplot2::zeroGrob())
  
  # for now we ignore hjust and vjust, it doesn't work yet
  hj <- 0
  vj <- 1
  
  css <- element$css %||% ""
  
  html_grob(
    label, x = x, y = y, hjust = hj, vjust = vj,
    width = element$width, height = element$height,
    css = css
  )
}


# CSS styling
css <- '
p { text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; }
.setosa { text-align: left; }
'

# plotting code
iris %>%
  mutate(
    # set class attribute to species name
    facet_label = glue('<p class = "{Species}">{Species}</p>')
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ facet_label) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text = element_html(css = css))
```

[image]

```r
# another example with different styling
css <- '
p { text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; font-style: italic; }
.setosa { background-color: #0072B2; color: white; }
.versicolor { background-color: #E69F00; }
.virginica { background-color: #009E73;  color: white; }
'

# plotting code
iris %>%
  mutate(
    # set class attribute to species name
    facet_label = glue('<p class = "{Species}">I. {Species}</p>')
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ facet_label) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(
      setosa = "#0072B2", versicolor = "#E69F00", virginica = "#009E73"
    ),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_html(css = css)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>